# parse.com - cloud code - what do i do with a pointer?

Tags: parse-platform

Someone doesn't understand what i want. I want to know what i can do with a pointer.

I have js cloud code.

I have a pointer.

What can i do with it?

Example:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Messages"); //POINTER QUERY
console.log(userMessages[0].get("messageId"));
console.log("end2");
query.equalTo("objectId",userMessages[position].get("messageId"));
```

In the example, userMessages  is the result of a prior cloud query.

This line

```
console.log(userMessages[0].get("messageId"));
```

helpfully outputs

```
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Messages","objectId":"5J4eOletgz"}
```

This is less useful than you might imagine. I cannot seem to *call* the objectId from it, and the query

```
query.equalTo("objectId",userMessages[position].get("messageId"));
query.find ({ ... });
```

returns nothing. Note that the query *should* find the pointer-object the pointer-points-to, but instead it helpfully throws the error

```
Error: 102 bad special key: __type
```

Which is just about useless.

What can i do with a pointer? 
Why don't the people at parse.com bother to write this stuff up anywhere?

That second question is more like a buddhist koan for them to meditate over, no need to respond!

Answer (score 6):

you can use:

```
userMessagesQuery.include("messageId")
```

before you execute your query that returns userMessages and you will get the entire object in "messageId" instead of just a pointer.

Also you use

```
userMessages[0].get("messageId").fetch({success:function(){}})
```

to get the full object if you don't want to use "include"

Suggestion: I'd rename "messageId" to "message" to make it clear that it's an object pointer and not an ID field.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is a Parse object with just the minimal data used for linking. If you want to get the rest of the data for a pointer (fully populate it), use the `fetch()` method.

If you just want the `objectId` from a pointer, you retrieve it just like you would any other Parse object, by using the `myPointer.objectId` property.

In your case the following would work, but isn't the most optimal solution:

```
// I would suggest renaming messageId if you're actually storing pointers
var messagePointer = userMessages[position].get("messageId");
query.equalTo("objectId", messagePointer.objectId);
```

Instead, as stated by @RipRyness, you could just change your previous query to `include()` the full object, avoiding many extra queries.

```
userMessagesQuery.include("messageId");

// ... later in success handler ...

// now a fully populated Message object
var message = userMessages[position].get("messageId");
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so a pointer is does not only point to a certain object, but it can *BE* that object.

In the query that returns the userMessages result, you can use the line .include("messageId") - this makes your query not only return a pointer to that object, it actually includes that object in place of the pointer.

After using the include statement, `userMessages[0].get("messageId")` will return the Message object linked that that userMessage object. You no longer need to query the Message collection to get the object.